# git svn show-externals Output Interpretation

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have an SVN repository that I cloned to Git using `git svn clone`. The repository has externals in SVN. When I use `git svn show-externals`, I get different external prefix prints for different commits. Examples of prints are:

```
/^/library/branches/binary
```

```
/^library/branches/binary
```

```
# /library/branches/test/
```

```
# /
```

```
/subproject/^/library/tip
```

what is the interpretation of each of these prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the official documentation at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html the only accepted relative specifiers are:

```
../

Relative to the URL of the directory on which the svn:externals property is set

^/

Relative to the root of the repository in which the svn:externals property is versioned

//

Relative to the scheme of the URL of the directory on which the svn:externals property is set

/

Relative to the root URL of the server on which the svn:externals property is versioned

^/../REPO-NAME

Relative to a sibling repository beneath the same SVNParentPath location as the repository in which the svn:externals is defined.
```

**Edit**

About the ones starting with `#` consider that externals are properties for SVN, so they can be commented out by prefixing the `#` symbol.

Comment: When I inspect the SVN server that I have, I see the first print I listed above is for a repository at (for example): www.foo.com/library/ and the external is from the branch: binary. So according to your reply, it seems that the first print should've been instead: `/library/branches/binary` without the additional `^/`. Am I missing something? Also, how about the other prints that I get that do not have equivalent in your answer?

Comment: If they are commented, does it mean they are still externals that I need to add in Git? what is the reason they are commented while in others they are not commented?

Comment: Sorry, but you have ask this to who wrote the code.